# How can use maven to build job with free Talend Open Studio

Tags: maven, maven-3, talend

I have some jobs maje with Talend Open Studio and I want use maven to export jobs in zip file to do automatic build.

Can I found an existing maven plugin to do that?

Can I build job with command line ?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I want do that for make automatic build and deployment on execution server without use a developer computer environment to build and integrate that in continuous integration process

Comment: In my case, I put in production a Talend Job who schedule somme sub job, and developer add some sub job or fix a bug in existing sub job. After he can run it in development environment with some context parameter specific to development environment (like url of database) and after need to re build the same code with production context. if i can do the build in something like jenkins I can ensure the code in development is the same like production and it is not human responsability (where error is possible)

Comment: in more complex situations, what i usually do is to keep the subjobs separate and in parallel and control the orchestration through touch files. No need to over complicate it. keep the jobs simple and your life becomes much easier. either you keep them very small and publish them separately or yo deploy everything in one go..it will be too much of an effort to automate it. like killing a mosquito with a nuclear bomb

Comment: Of course, it is handy and especially when you do lot of releases frequently on large projects, going with automated deployment pipeline starting from dev to prod (with human interaction if required) is the way to go, so this is completely valid request.

Answer (score 1):

Talend CommandLine is only available in Talend Enterprise Subscription Version. There is no job script in Talend open studio products.

For more information about how to use command line to build the job, please visit this [link](https://help.talend.com/reader/zG7iZ5VB0XkesgeKP4qk_A/w9WipT881wISUB7x1sPkAQ).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but complex !

You will have to change pom settings.
Change the file `maven_user_setting.xml` and `settings.xml`
Check Offline in maven preferences.

Then with command line like following you can build your project :

```
mvn -B -s C:\Talend\TOS_DI-Win32-20200219_1130-V7.3.1\configuration\maven_user_settings.xml install -l C:/Talend/lastGenerated.log -P default-settings,!include-java-sources,!include-maven-resources,!include-items,include-libs,!include-binaries,include-running-log4j,include-log4j,include-contexts,!include-test-sources,!include-test-reports,include-xmlMappings,include-running-xmlMappings,packaging-and-assembly,!ci-builder -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dci.builder.skip=true
```

Comment: hello, can you explain the changes in `maven_user_setting.xml` and `settings.xml` please :)

Comment: Change the file maven_user_setting.xml and settings.xml....change it to what ???